# The "Full name" field of Moodle doesn't show the name

Tags: moodle

The "Full name" field of Moodle doesn't show the name. Instead, it shows the text "emailaddress".

[image]

Comment: Can you click on the link for the full name,so it takes you to the user profile - then see what their first name and last name are?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that someone has used the "Language customisation" feature of Moodle and changed the "fullnamedisplay" language string from the default value of:

```
{$a->firstname} {$a->lastname}
```

(which displays the first name, followed by the last name)
instead, setting it to:

```
emailaddress
```

(which just displays the literal text "emailaddress")

I suggest you navigate to Site admin > Language > Language customisations, select "English (en)" and "Open language pack for editing". Then search for "String identifier" "fullnamedisplay" (without quotes). Then delete the "Local customisation" and click "Save changes to the language pack".